# Why 0 && 1 is 1 while 1 && 0 is 0 in ruby?

Tags: ruby, operators

In Ruby, why are the following lines true?

```
0 && 1 == 1
1 && 0 == 0
```

Why are they different and aren't both 0?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

*Boolean* AND operator `&&` returns its second operand if first is not false. `0` and `1` are `true` in boolean expressions in Ruby. Only `nil` and `false` are false in boolean expressions.

```
nil && 15 # => nil
15 && 17 # => 17
15 && nil # => nil
```

Answer (score 7):

`0` and `1` don't represent truth values in Ruby. In ruby anything that is not `nil` or `false` is true. If you add to this that:

> The and and && operators evaluate their first operand. If false, the expression returns false; otherwise, the expression returns the value of the second operand.

You get that you evaluate `true && true` and then the result of the second operand is returned. If you wrote `3 && 4`, you would have gotten `4`!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to excellent answers here:

You probably confuse **logical** and **bitwise** ANDs.

```
$ irb
1.9.3-p125 :001 > 1 & 0
 => 0 
1.9.3-p125 :002 > 0 & 1
 => 0
```